# SQLScript: scalar type is not allowed

Tags: sql, hana, sql-scripts

I have the following sql command:

```
SELECT DFT(weighted, 32768 ORDER BY rel_id).REAL as four FROM :fith
```

This function returns an array with 32769 elements in one cell.[image]

Now I want to use the `unnest`function to split the result. Therefore I need to save the results in a variable.

The following command throws an error:

```
my_array = SELECT DFT(weighted, 32768 ORDER BY rel_id).REAL as four FROM :fith;
===>    invalid datatype: Column FOUR of table variable MY_ARRAY has an unsupported data type (ARRAY)
```

Well okay... after the declaration of my `my_array` to an array, I'm getting this error:

```
    declare my_array double array;
    my_array = SELECT DFT(weighted, 32768 ORDER BY rel_id).REAL as four FROM :fith;
==>scalar type is not allowed: MY_ARRAY:
```

Why do I want to do this over such a detour?
The documentation says:

> The UNNEST function cannot be referenced directly in a FROM clause of
>   a SELECT statement

Whats wrong? What can I do now?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that you are trying to put an SQL-result in an array. 
You could however store the SQL-result in a local table variable.

In your case I would **create a cursor and loop over the result set**.

**Within the loop-body** you can then **split the cell-content** using a custom split-string function as described in the thread [HANA: Split string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27709213/993494)