# Query to split delimited string in HANA

Tags: hana

We have requirement in sap HANA to split comma separated string into rows -

```
string - A,B
```

We want output as-

```
col1 
A
B
```

Is it possible using SAP HANA?

Best Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HANA: Split string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27709088/hana-split-string)

Comment: Spot on Serban! This is the same requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following [SQLScript library to split text into table](http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/hana-database-builtin-sqlscript-library-string-functions.aspx) form

```
do
begin using SQLSCRIPT_STRING as lib;

declare tbl table (result varchar(10));
declare strVal varchar(200);
strVal = 'A,B';
tbl := lib:split_to_table( :strVal, ',' );

select result as col1 from :tbl;

end;
```

Comment: is it available in HANA 1.0 SPS 12?

Comment: I don't think so, I tested it on hana2sp03. I checked now it is new with HANA 2.0 SPS03