# How to split multiple values from a row into separate rows?

Tags: sql, hana

I want to split multiple values from a row into a separate row in **sap hana** sql.
table :

```
 id  name
 1   kabil,arasan
```

but I want an output like this:

```
id  name
1   kabil  
1   arasan
```

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items! It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: tnx for your reply...   but I'm just trying how to enter multiple values in a single column and how to split that multiple values... that's y I'm posted this question....

Comment: You can do it by creating table type function to split comma separated values and then `cross apply` with the values. Similar solution, I can provide in `SQL SERVER`.

Answer (score 3):

1. try to avoid csv-like data in columns, e.g. normalize during ETL process
2. you can use a procedure, see [[HANA: Split string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27709088/hana-split-string][1])
3. without a procedure you can use the following SQL (restriction: it assumes a maximum number of values in your csv-field). I would use it only for adhoc purposes.

   ```
   CREATE COLUMN TABLE "TEST_SPLIT"(
       "SOME_KEY" VARCHAR(10),
       "CSV_STR" VARCHAR(1000) );

   INSERT INTO "TEST_SPLIT" ("SOME_KEY", "CSV_STR") VALUES ('1', 'hello world');
   INSERT INTO "TEST_SPLIT" ("SOME_KEY", "CSV_STR") VALUES ('2', 'one,two,three');
   INSERT INTO "TEST_SPLIT" ("SOME_KEY", "CSV_STR") VALUES ('3', NULL);

   Select * from 
   ( select "SOME_KEY" "KEY", "ELEMENT_NUMBER" "ORD", 
          SUBSTR_REGEXPR('(?<=^|,)([^,]*)(?=,|$)' IN "TEST_SPLIT"."CSV_STR" OCCURRENCE "SERIES"."ELEMENT_NUMBER" GROUP 1) "VAL"
     from "TEST_SPLIT",
          SERIES_GENERATE_INTEGER(1, 1, 10 ) "SERIES" -- replace 10 with your max. number of values in CSV-Field
   )
   where "VAL" is not null
   order by "KEY", "ORD"
   ```

   [1]: [HANA: Split string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27709088/hana-split-string)

Answer (score 0):

Slight tweaking of the use of the SUBSTR_REGEXPR function. I've used this just last week in Hana as a Script_View and can confirm it works.

```
Begin
VAR_OUT =
    select *
    from ( select
    ST.PARAM, -- Source table id
    NT.Element_Number, -- Occurrence number within source table row
SUBSTR_REGEXPR( '([;])([^;]*)(?=;)'
IN   CONCAT(CONCAT(';',ST.VALUE),';')
     OCCURRENCE NT.Element_Number
    GROUP 2
    ) splitted      -- string piece
from 
"_SYS_BIC"."Financial_Planning_and_Analysis/ZZTPARPAR_SOURCE" as ST, -- source  table
SERIES_GENERATE_INTEGER(1, 0, 10 ) as NT -- numbers table
    ) tbl
where splitted is not null
order by PARAM, Element_Number;
End
```

[Before and After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8T4b.png)